# Can you make the constructor of base class in derived class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Is this possible that we can make the constructor of base class in derived class?

```
public class A 
    {
     // some stuff
    }

    public class B:A
    {

     public A()
     { }

     public B() { }
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what purpose would this serve?  Is this an idle curiosity, or is there an actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What sorcery is this?

Comment: This is probably an interview question.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't do that and it wouldn't be sensible. You can call  base class constructor in child class using [`base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword.

```
public class B : A
{
    public B()
        : base() //base class default constructor call. 
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Constructor of a class has to be in its own class.

But you can invoke `A`'s constructor in `B` by `new A()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 public abstract class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            ExecuteConstructor();
        }

        protected abstract void ExecuteConstructor();
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public B() { }

        protected override void ExecuteConstructor()
        {
            // implementation of your constructor to run in A 
        }
    }
```